# Ajax response doesn't equal what I think it should

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to call a `displayUsers` function, if response equals "*loggedIn*" (response is coming from echo statement in php for ajax request). It always jumps straight to the else statement and doesn't execute  `displayUsers()`. However, when I alert response it displays loggedIn.

**Here is my code:**

```
   function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, asynch, responseHandler) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, asynch);

    if (method == "POST") {
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                responseHandler(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    request.send(data);
}

//loginCheck
    function loginCheck() {
        var username = document.getElementById("usernameLogin").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;
        var data="usernameLoginAttempt="+username+"&passwordLoginAttempt="+password;
        ajaxRequest("../PHP/CODE/login_check.php", "POST", data, true, loginCheckResponse);
    }

    function loginCheckResponse(response) {
    //check response, if it is "loggedIn" then call show users function
    alert(response);
    if (response == "loggedIn") {
        displayUsers();
    } else {
        alert("Login Failed. Please try again.")

    }

}
```

Comment: show how your PHP return the data.

Comment: Are you sure the character case is corret.
try response.toLowerCase()== "loggedin"

Comment: character case is correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
// response is an object which you get from ajex.
// You have not written how you call loginCheckResponse()
// call like loginCheckResponse(response.<variable which you return from service page>)
function loginCheckResponse(response)
{
    //check response, if it is "loggedIn" then call show users function
    alert(response);
    if (response == "loggedIn") {
        displayUsers();
    } else {
        alert("Login Failed. Please try again.")
    }

}
```

Comment: added how I have called loginCheckResponse().

Comment: you can call this function from success in ajax and pass the value in this function, As i told response.<variable which you return from service page>

Comment: loginCheckResponse() is calling... the problem is the if statement. the response variable is equal to the ajax response request.responsetext. when I alert response it tells me that request.responsetext is equal to "loggedIn", however it keeps jumping to the else statement and therefore missing displayUsers();

Comment: obviously quotes will not come there,,,, quotes uses for only string or character variable to assign value in that,,,

Answer (score 1):

Changed my code to:

```
    //logged in
function loginCheckResponse(response) {

    if(response.trim()=="loggedIn"){
        displayUsers();
    }
    else{
        alert("Login Failed. Please try again.");
    }

}
```

It now works. Thanks for the help anyway people.